# Using Eclipselink 2.7.7 as external JPA with OpenLiberty

Tags: open-liberty

I've been at this for some days now, and could use some help. I have an application which uses EclipseLink 2.7.7 and also the SDO feature. I run it, for a test, as a standalone Java app, using the following jars downloaded as part of the EclipseLink offering;

```
eclipselink.jar
commonj.sdo_2.1.1_v201112051852.jar
```

I need this code to run under OpenLiberty, using a Session Bean and an Entity. The code doesn't work under OpenLiberty if I just rely on the built-in JPA2.2 in Liberty.

I tried to follow these instructions to replace the JPA: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jpa.html

But, the instructions list a bunch of jar files that don't exist in my EclipseLink download. E.g.;

```
<file name="${server.config.dir}/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar/>
<file name="${server.config.dir}/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar"/>
<file name="${server.config.dir}/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar"/>
<file name="${server.config.dir}/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar"/>
<file name="${server.config.dir}/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.jar"/>
<file name="${server.config.dir}/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar"/>
```

Also, I tried bundling the 2 jar files in the same ear as my code, and deploying that. But, no matter what I do, whenever I deploy to Liberty, the "JPA2.2" feature gets added to the server, and my code fails.

Does anyone know how to get Liberty to stop adding the "JPA2.2" feature when I deploy?

Comment: Are you deploying using Eclipse? I know that if you are using Eclipse IDE then the projects facets will be scanned and matching features will be added.

Comment: I am indeed using Eclipse to deploy. I tried to disable the JPA Facet on the Eclipse project but Eclipse won't let me do so.

Answer (score 3):

**Deploying EclipseLink as a third-party on Liberty**

Unfortunately, as you discovered, the EclipseLink that Liberty ships to support JPA 2.2 does not contain the EclipseLink SDO features. We ship EclipseLink in WebSphere as a persistence provider for the Java EE component: JPA. This means we do not ship (and then support) other sections of EclipseLink that are not mandated by the Java Persistence specification (DBWS, SDO, MOXY (which is a JAXB implementation)).

As you discovered, if you want SDO functionality in Liberty, you will need to supply this as a shared library.

There are two features in Liberty that I want to point out:

1. `jpa-2.2`: This feature provides two things to your applications: the JPA API bundles (the javax.persistence.* packages that come from the Java EE spec) and a persistence provider that implements those API bundles (EclipseLink)
2. `jpaContainer-2.2`: This feature provides one thing to your applications: just the JPA API bundles (the javax.persistence.* packages that come from the Java EE spec)

If you are planning on configuring your own JPA 2.2 supported, third-party persistence provider, in Liberty, it is recommended that you use the `jpaContainer-2.2`. This will give you the JPA API bundles that your provider will be implementing. It also means you SHOULD NOT provide your own `javax.persistence.*` API bundles in your shared library or there may be conflicts.

I notice that you are attempting to use `eclipselink.jar` in your shared library. I highly recommend NOT using that bundle. That is a JSE bootstrapping bundle that contains all EclipseLink features AND the javax.persistence packages. It is built as a convenience bundle for development environments in JSE and is not intended for production. Since it contains the javax.persistence.* packages, it can cause classloading issues as it collides with the JPA API packages WebSphere provides with both JPA features (`jpa-2.2` and `jpaContainer-2.2`)

This is also the reason that the KnowledgeCenter instructions list separate bundles (asm, antlr, core, jpa, jpql, modelgen). These are the bundles that WebSphere ships to support JPA and you can find the versions of these bundles on Maven Central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence). If you want to use SDO, I recommend downloading https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.sdo and any other dependencies that it requires (like `org.eclipse.persistence.core`, `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy`)

**Liberty feature update problem**

If you are deploying Liberty in Eclipse (with `IBM Liberty Developer Tools` installed) and are having issues with automatic feature detection, you can turn that off from the Preferences section:

```
Window > Preferences > Server > Liberty Server
Uncheck `Enable automatic feature detection`
```

Comment: Will, thank you for the comprehensive reply. I will take some time to digest it, and try to correctly use Liberty jpaContainer-2.2, and the appropriate Bundles from Maven for SDO support. Cheers!